# How to increase backend services quota in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I'm using Kubernetes and I'm trying to create an [ingress resource](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/ingress.html). I create it using:

```
$ kubectl create -f my-ingress.yaml
```

I wait a while and a load balancer doesn't seem to be created. Running:

```
$ kubectl describe ing my-ingress
```

returns:

```
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                SubobjectPath   Reason      Message
  ───────── ────────    ─────   ────                ─────────────   ──────      ───────
  46s       46s     1   {loadbalancer-controller }          ADD     my-ingress
  23s       11s     2   {loadbalancer-controller }          GCE :Quota  googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded.  Limit: 3.0
```

Is there a way to increase the number of backend services that can be created?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to increase the quota assigned for your project. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas for the explanation of resource quotas, and follow the link on that page to check and/or request a quota increase.

Answer (score 15):

You can follow below steps to increase the resource quotas in your GCP project :

**Step 1 :** Open https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas

**Step 2 :** Select **Project** from the dropdown list

**Step 3 :** Select the service for which you want the quota to be increased and then click **EDIT QUOTAS**

**Step 4 :** Enter you **Name**, **Email** & **Phone** and then click **Next**

**Step 5 :** Enter **New Quota Limit** and **Description** about your request and Click Done

**Step 6 :** **Submit Request**

Within few minutes your quota should be increased

**References :**
https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas

Comment: After you've sumitted the quota request. You will get email from the support team, saying that the quota request take two business days to process.

Comment: The actual wait time is however from a few minutes up to two business days.